# SQL: For each column1 find it's row with max value of column2

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: Table To SELECT from]

I want to get for EACH id the row that has the biggest value in feedbacks. So my expected results should look like this:

[image: Wanted Result]

I've tried to do this:

```
SELECT  id, course_number, rate_average, max(feedbacks)
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY id;
```

And I'm getting one row per ID but the row doesn't contain the data of the right row in the original table.

Oh and I'm using mysql.

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: @GurV I removed the SQL Server tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t.*
from your_table t
inner join (
    select
        id, max(feedbacks) feedbacks
    from your_table
    group by id
) t2 on t.id = t2.id and t.feedbacks = t2.feedbacks;
```

It finds id and maximum feedback and join it with the original table to get the relevant rows.

Please note if there are multiple rows with same id and feedbacks, all those rows will be returned.

Comment: That's awesome I think you've solved it. but what does t2 stand for here?

Comment: it's alias for the table or in this case subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per id, then think "filter", not "aggregate".  One approach is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.feedbacks = (select max(t2.feedbacks)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.id = t.id
                    );
```

Note:  If multiple rows have the same maximum, then this will return all the rows for the id.  If this is an issue, you should probably ask another question and specify what you want to return in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by adding a row number group by `id` column order by descending order of `feedbacks` column.

**Query**

```
select t1.``id`, t1.`course_number`, t1.`rate_average`, t1.`feedbacks` from 
(
    select `id`, `course_number`, `rate_average`, `feedbacks`, 
    (
        case `id` when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := `id` end 
    ) as `rn` 
    from `your_table_name` t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by `id`, `feedbacks` desc 
)t1 
where t1.`rn` = 1;
```